# Parsing multiple numbers out of a string Java

Tags: java, parsing

I have a problem for my java class where i have to parse through multiple .txt files and extract strings of math problems and compare the answer in the string against the actual answer of the problem. I've been able to read and check problems with two single digit numbers but i cannot get pass that. I have to be able to check problems with up to 4 numbers of any length, and decimals with six places (0.000001). 
I also cannot use regex or arrays in this code.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.NumberOfDocuments;

public class CheckAnswers
{
private static double correct = 0;
private static double numQuestions = 0;

public static void Test(Object newline) throws IOException, ParseException
{
    while (((Scanner) newline).hasNext())
    {
        String line = ((Scanner) newline).nextLine();
        // String line = "8 - 5 = 3";
        //                0123456789

        String num1 = line.substring(0, 1);
        double firstNum = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        //double firstNum = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(num1).intValue();
        String num2 = line.substring(4, 5);
        double secondNum = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(num2).intValue();
        String answer = line.substring(8, 9);
        double userAnswer = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(answer).intValue();

        int loopExit = 0;
        while (loopExit == 0)
        {
            int checkSubtraction = line.indexOf('-');
            if (checkSubtraction != -1)
            {
                loopExit++;
                Subtraction(line, firstNum, secondNum, userAnswer);
            }
            int checkAddition = line.indexOf('+');
            if (checkAddition != -1)
            {
                loopExit++;
                Addition(line, firstNum, secondNum, userAnswer);
            }
            int checkDivision = line.indexOf('/');
            if (checkDivision != -1)
            {
                loopExit++;
                Division(line, firstNum, secondNum, userAnswer);
            }
            int checkMultiplication = line.indexOf('*');
            if (checkMultiplication != -1)
            {
                loopExit++;
                Multiplication(line, firstNum, secondNum, userAnswer);
            }
        }
        numQuestions++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number correct: " + correct + " out of " + numQuestions);
    double percentGrade = ((correct * 100) / numQuestions);
    System.out.println("Grade: " + percentGrade + "%");
}

public static void Subtraction(String line, double firstNum, double secondNum,
        double userAnswer) throws ParseException
{
    double keyNum = firstNum - secondNum;
    if (userAnswer == keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        correct++;
    }
    if (userAnswer != keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}

public static void Addition(String line, double firstNum, double secondNum,
        double userAnswer) throws ParseException
{
    double keyNum = firstNum + secondNum;
    if (userAnswer == keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        correct++;
    }
    if (userAnswer != keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}

public static void Multiplication(String line, double firstNum, double secondNum,
        double userAnswer) throws ParseException
{
    double keyNum = firstNum * secondNum;
    if (userAnswer == keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        correct++;
    }
    if (userAnswer != keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}

public static void Division(String line, double firstNum, double secondNum,
        double userAnswer) throws ParseException
{
    double keyNum = firstNum / secondNum;
    if (userAnswer == keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct");
        correct++;
    }
    if (userAnswer != keyNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input and your desired output. It will help us to better understand your problem.

Comment: And also what "not able to get past" means. Are you getting an exception? Invalid output? Can you not use `nextInt()` instead of manually pulling characters from the line?

Comment: I suggest you start by changing `Test(Object newline)`  to `Test(Scanner newline)` and use something like `Double num1 = newline.nextDouble();
String oper = newline.next();
Double num2 = newline.nextDouble();
Double answer = newline.nextDouble();`

Answer (score 0):

RegEx would be the easiest to use since you have variable length strings of numbers with various operations applied to them. Since you don't want to use that, you should at least tokenize the string on operators (+, -, /, *, =) and trim off whitespace. [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) will help here.

Using split might be problematic unless you can guarantee that there will be spaces between the numbers and operators. You will need to process the string recursively with additional tokenizers, or split at each token and process accordingly.